# How often are です and 〜ます used among friends?

Tags: politeness, word-usage

since they are polite forms are they ever often used in informal settings among friends? or would people think you’re being overly polite?

Comment: Related: [How do Japanese speakers transition from polite to plain form amongst friends?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25109/5010) and [Can polite and casual Japanese be combined?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64467/5010)

Comment: overly polite ですが、ふざけて使うことはあります。あと、学校の友達か、会社で親しい人か、など親密度によるかと思います。