# What are the social implications of being too polite lingustically?

Tags: politeness, culture

Reviewing some basic keigo forms, I was wondering what happens if you express yourself too polite... I heared that is not uncommon for (elder) couples to use keigo to express their uttermost respect towards their partner and this is generally perceived as "cute"/positive by Japanese people. Conversly in most Indo-European cultures beeing overly polite to people close to you would sometimes be considered cold/distant/rude.

So my questions:

> What would be the general reaction of Japanese people, if one were to
>   use too polite language forms for a given situation? Are there certain
>   kinds of situation in which beeing too polite would be particular
>   positivly/negatively perceived by Japanese people?

Comment: This is a good question! Keep in mind that the answer will have a LOT to do with your perceived Japanese language skill level. People's reaction to overuse of polite language by a novice Japanese learner vs a skilled JSL speaker vs a native speaker will generally be very different.

Comment: And the inverse: the better you are at managing this, the less you’re treated as a learner (more so than many other dimensions of proficiency).

Comment: In a casual setting, the reaction would be pretty much the same as if you were in bar with your (non Japanese) friends and asked them: "Would you terribly mind if I were to humbly allow myself to pour you a drink?"

Answer (score 3):

Unsurprisingly, a sudden *switch* to polite speech or keigo usually means a psychological distance, anger or a serious mood.

However, if a couple uses keigo on a daily basis, that's another story. Traditionally, the concept of gender role was much more prevailing than today in Japan, and it was not uncommon for a wife to use keigo to her husband. In [*Sazae-san*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sazae-san), you can hear Fune regularly use mild keigo to her husband, Namihei. (Of course they are regarded as a stereotypical, good old example of a happy Japanese family.) Even today, some people are [very slow to switch to plain form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/64475/5010) depending on his/her character, and a few may keep using keigo even after a marriage. It usually means nothing.

Comment: "psychological distance, anger or a serious mood" ... or a good-natured fun, like passing salt with a grin and かしこまりました. :)