# What does the word 「いいんスよ」 mean?

Tags: katakana, colloquial-language, contractions

Here is the conversation that includes the word.

> A: そんな　つめてえこといわないで...
>   　 ひと目{め}で**いいんスよ** ほんのちょいとあうだけでいいんだから
>
> B: だめっていったら　だめーっ

And I'm curious why the syllable 「ス」 in the word has to be written in katakana?

Comment: It's a n informal contraction of です. First time I came into contact with it was playing Final Fantasy X all those years ago (in which it's used extensively by Tidus).

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ス in this case is a colloquial shortening of です.

I think the reason people write it with Katakana is that it makes it easier to tell that's a new word rather than んす being a typographical error for something else.

If you look for っす you can find entries that explain that this is a [丁寧]{ていねい} colloquialism (http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%99). Our fearless moderator points out that the small-つ is probably avoided due to "superheavy syllable" it creates.

I decode the sentences as follows:

> A: そんな冷たいことを言わないで、一目でいいんですよ。

Comment: <A: そのような冷たいことを言わないで、一目でいいんですよ。> might be marginally better.  Oh BTW..  <I'm trying to find a Japanese source about the ス>  Is that worth pursuing? As long as your guess is correct, you don't necessarily have to locate any "evidence" for a mere colloquialism.

Comment: I don't think whether it's a colloquialism makes any difference in terms of documentability.  @virmaior I think it's often ッス, but っ is avoided after ん because it creates a superheavy syllable.  You might try searching for っす or ッス instead.

Comment: @eltonjohn as an answerer (and for my own sake as a non-native speaker), I like to source things just as good practice -- in case the OP wants to confirm or understand further how something works.

Comment: @virmaior: <I like to source things just as good practice> Alright, I got it. Please understand that I did not intend to discourage your inquiring mind.