# Past negative tense じゃなかったでした

Tags: grammar, politeness, tense

We can use じゃなかったです for past tense, but can we replace the です with でした so that it becomes じゃなかったでした? Why or why not?

Comment: [related](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29891/11830)

Comment: じゃなかったです or じゃなかったでした　are some bad expression.The best expression is ではありませんでしたか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negative past forms are:

1. なかった
2. なかったです
3. ありませんでした

In 1 and 2, the tense change is **already realised** by ない→なかった, and です just acts as a helper to add politeness. なかったでした does not exist because です will not inflect to show tense since it's just a politeness helper here.

In 3, the tense change is realised by でした, but note that in the case of present tense, ありませんです does not exist because the politeness is already accounted for by ます(manifested as ません here), so です is not required as a politeness helper in the present tense.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. じゃなかったです is a confusing form because it's a colloquialism, and thus is only "grammatical" de facto. The proper form is じゃありませんでした, or without contractions, ではありませんでした. じゃなかったでした is completely incorrect and can't be used under any circumstances.

Comment: You don't really answer the "why or why not". You just say that じゃなかったです is a confusing form. You also don't explain why じゃなかったでした is "completely incorrect".

Comment: I'm conflicted to vote on this because you have a point about the lack of explanation. But it is extremely helpful to know the proper conjugations so I will neither upvote nor downvote