# Variations in polite negations: ありません, ないです, -ません

Tags: grammar, history, negation

Negations that consistently take -ない in the plain form show differences in the polite version:
食べない -> 食べません
で(は)ない -> で(は)ありません
but
大きくない -> 大きくないです

Why the inconsistency? Is it due to history?

Comment: Hm? You can say 大きくありません, right?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29889/do-%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-and-%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-have-the-same-level-of-politeness-as-%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93-and-%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-h

Comment: Also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2574/9831

Answer (score 4):

You'd normally see/hear... or, you'd normally be expected to use, in formal situations:

> (verb) 知らない -> 知り**ません**
>   (noun+copula / na-adjective) ではない -> ではあり**ません**/じゃあり**ません**
>   (i-adjective) 大きくない -> 大きくあり**ません**

You'd see/hear ～ないです in rather informal situations, like casual conversation:

> (verb) 知らない -> 知らない**です**
>   (noun+copula / na-adjective) ではない/じゃない -> ではない**です**/じゃない**です**
>   (i-adjective) 大きくない -> 大きくない**です**

So.. they look quite consistent... no?

Comment: 食べる  cannot be written as 食べるです。
食べない can be written as 食べないです。
食べた cannot be written as 食べたです。
食べなかった　can be written as  食べなかったです。

However, can 食べなかったです be written as 食べないでした?

Comment: @Artificial 食べないでした sounds incorrect.. You can say 食べなかったです or 食べませんでした.