# What dialect replaces です with a shorter version of it (ーす)?

Tags: pronunciation, copula

The title pretty much explains itself, here is an example: [Nio from Akuma no Riddle](https://youtu.be/jLedbLnI-vg?t=31), the whole thing has been bugging me for awhile, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you thinking of っす? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-does-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%99-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-mean

Answer (score 3):

Can't watch the video, but if it's っす (as in そうっすね instead of そうですね) it's not a dialect, just a personal "style" of the speaker. There are countless other "styles" a person can use other than っす, e.g. でげす (which was used by men around the end of the Edo Period to early Meiji Period but sometimes used nowadays by manga/anime characters), でちゅ, which is like baby talk in Japanese, ってばよ, which is Naruto's style, and so on...

**Edit:**
Just watched the video and I confirm that my answer above is correct. The female character said:

> 高級{こうきゅう}食材｛しょくざい}ばっかで美味{うま}そう**っす**ね

It's just her speaking style, which has the same meaning as:

> 高級{こうきゅう}食材｛しょくざい}ばっかで美味{うま}そう**です**ね