# Meaning of ちはース

Tags: colloquial-language, manga, greetings, abbreviations, casual

Context: a boy shouts 「**ちはース**」 after seeing that a fan club for a boxer has only female members. He is happy to discover this since he is the kind of guy that always tries to flirt with pretty girls.

I understand that this is an exclamation expressing surprise, but is it common? Does it have an exact meaning or it is only onomatopoeic?

Also, is it vulgar? Something like "holy shit", or is it more similar to "wow"? I am asking this because the character shouting it often speaks in a vulgar way.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b3aF.jpg) you can see the original page. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is just "Hi".

- こんちゃ/こんちわ/ちわ/ちは/etc is a very casual version of こんにちは. Of course this は is pronounced "wa".
- For "ーす", see: [What does っす at the end of a sentence mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36/5010)

Jisho.org also has an [entry for this](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%8F%E3%81%A3%E3%81%99). Other variations include ちわっす, こんちゃっす, ちゃーっす, ちゃーす, ちっす and ちーす.

Comment: Does this mean that the speaker is greeting someone, or does the Japanese usage of こんにちは extend its usage in the same way as the English 'hello'? That is, can it be used upon making a discovery, e.g. "Hello, that's an interesting thing I've just discovered".

Comment: @user3856370 He's not surprised, and this is not an exclamatory phrase at all. It's just plain "hello" said in a loud voice. Please forget "wow", "holy shit" or anything similar.

Comment: @naruto Maybe it'd be something like sup!

Comment: Wonder if it's odd to switch from hiragana to katakana in midword like this, or if this just shows i don't read a lot of manga?

Comment: @NathanHughes I think it's just that you don't read a lot of manga. :) They do that often. However, I don't think it is common outside manga.

Comment: @Ringil Oh, it's contracted "wassup"? Then it should be similar, but by using "ーす", he's also trying to be a little polite.

Comment: @NathanHughes This ス is essentially です. With that in mind, please read: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/64987/5010