# Difference between "行くんスカ?" and "行くんですか"

Tags: translation, usage

I think both of them have a similar meaning but the use of んスカ is puzzling, like what is the literal translation of it?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer without knowing where you saw these, perhaps a bit more context might help?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes です can be abbreviated to す or っす, as you seem to have guessed. There is an answer here about that:

[What does っす at the end of a sentence mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-does-%E3%81%A3%E3%81%99-at-the-end-of-a-sentence-mean)